# does recv always return the same amount of data passed to send?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

If I have two sockets (`AF_INET`, `SOCK_STREAM`, `IPPROTO_IPV4`) connected together and I issue a `send()` of 32 bytes on one end, is the `recv()` operation that reads the data on the other end guaranteed to return the same amount of data in a single call?

Comment: @close-voter This is not a question that requires code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee. In fact, by default, multiple consecutive short writes will be combined into a single network packet, which will be received in a single `recv()`. (This is known as [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).)

If the data you are transmitting needs to be framed in a specific way, you will need to include data to define that framing as part of the data you transmit. One simple approach is to delimit your data with a special character, like a newline or a null byte; another is to transmit the length of each frame before its data. (There are many other ways to frame data; these are just a few ideas to get started with.)

Comment: Also [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [Binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/), [ASN.1](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/), etc.